# Count number of occurrences in file. conditional pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell, design-patterns, grep, matching

Sorry if the title doesn't make it clear.

I have a file to be read every 15 mins and find a particular pattern in it (e.g. timeout). File does not have any fixed update frequency.

Outcome expected:-
1. if pattern is found 3 times in 15 mins, run command1.
2. if pattern is found 5 times in 15 mins, run command2.

File to be read from last read position for each check.

Thanks,
GRV

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The crudest implementation is to read the total number of occurrences of your pattern each time and store that count in a file.  Each 15 minute interval, compare the current count with what was stored earlier and so on.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a `cron` job. It is more complicated than other solutions but it is very reliable (even if your "check script" crashes, it will be called up again by `cron` after the period elapses). The `cron` could be:

```
*/15 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /folder/checkscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `env DISPLAY=:0` might not be needed in your case, or it might be needed, depending on your script (note: you might need to adapt this to your case, run echo `$DISPLAY` to find out your variable on the case).

Your `"checkscript"` could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/checkVarCount ]; then oldCheckVar="$(cat /tmp/checkVarCount)"; else oldCheckVar="0"; fi
checkVar="$(grep -o "pattern" /folder/file | wc -l)"
echo "$checkVar" > /tmp/checkVarCount
checkVar="$(($checkVar-$oldCheckVar))"
if [ "$checkVar" -eq 3 ]; then command1; fi
if [ "$checkVar" -eq 5 ]; then command2; fi
exit
```

It is not included on your question, but if you meant to run the commands as well if the pattern is found 4 times or 7 times, then you could change the relevant parts above to:

```
if [ "$checkVar" -ge 3 ] && [ "$checkVar" -lt 5 ]; then command1; fi
if [ "$checkVar" -ge 5 ]; then command2; fi
```

Comment: What's the significance of setting the display with the cron job?

Comment: Some programs can't run without this environment variable when called from `cron`.